# How to get a sense of how busy is the server

Tags: sql-server

I am not in IT infrastructure team. But I have a SQL database server. We are having this intermittent problem with Dynamics SL and everyone in the company sort of pointing the finger that the server is too busy, working too hard, ect2. I disagree with the assessment and would like to get some concrete data from the server to give to my co worker

I was thinking to capture batch request per second and presented the data. 
My Question:

1. Do batch request per second the right approach to see how
   busy/overloaded/overworked the server is?
2. if yes then how do I capture this?
3. do I have to keep SQL profiler open and save the data daily?
4. is there an automated way that allow me to capture some sort of metrics on how much request is hitting the server?
5. If batch request per second is not the right data, then what would be the right info to get? and how to get it?

thanks

Comment: Oh my please do not use Profiler

Comment: A server being busy is not a problem a server not responding to requests in timely fashion can be issue. You are moving in wrong way. To answer this question it would be better if baseline would be there for server. Batch request can tell you your server is busy but it does not always points to problem

Comment: I am not trying to point to the problem. I am just trying to put money where mouth is. I just want to present to the IT team that the assumption that the server is overloaded is incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't buy into an analysis done solely on batch per second. At the very least I would ask for a baseline to compare against (eg. "6 month ago we were handling 50 b/s, now we're doing 500 b/s"). Simply stating "our server handles 342 batches per second" does not say much. At the very least you could capture a timeline and say something like "there are daily spikes of b/s at 9:30 am". But you can do much, much more.

To start with, you need to learn some basics about the performance toolset at your disposal. First and foremost [`logman.exe`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490956.aspx). Absolutely read [Windows Performance Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc749249.aspx) (all the sub-chapters too, there's a lot to learn there).

Next I would recommend reading [How to analyse SQL Server performance](http://rusanu.com/2014/02/24/how-to-analyse-sql-server-performance/#sample_profiling). It really answers a lot of your questions.

And now the answers to your questions:

> Do batch request per second the right approach to see how busy/overloaded/overworked the server is?

No.

> if yes then how do I capture this?

Not applicable.

> do I have to keep SQL profiler open and save the data daily?

Never. Even *if* trace events would be relevant, never SQL Profiler. Read about [SQL Trace](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191006(v=sql.105).aspx) and server side tracing.

> is there an automated way that allow me to capture some sort of metrics on how much request is hitting the server?

Yes, many. the engine itself cpature a lot of info in wait stats, the OS exposes perf counter and a rich toolset around them. Read the articles linked above.

> If batch request per second is not the right data, then what would be the right info to get? and how to get it?

Ditto, read the articles linked above to get some basic info and narrow down your question.